# Unable to send pdf file via intent to any application except Whatsapp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to share a pdf file(which was created using pdfbox library) using intent to other apps, but when I send it to Gmail or telegraph, I get error called unsupported attachment. However, I am able to successfully send it via Whatsapp. Here's my code for sharing:

```
 fun shareIntent(context: Context, position: Int) {
         val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
         sharingIntent.type = "application/pdf"
         val file= docAdapter.getItem(position).path
         val uri = Uri.parse(file)
         sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
         sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri  )
         context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"))
     }
```

Comment: Use FileProvider to get an uri for your file. Instead of Uri.parse().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079536/intent-action-view-not-working-on-android-10-os?noredirect=1#comment120327639_68079536

Comment: @blackapps Thank you so much! It did work. I wish you good luck!