# Intent.ACTION_VIEW not working on Android 10 OS

Tags: android, android-10.0, actionview

In my application am having a pdf which is to be printed by selecting the installed apps in the device. Till Android 9 OS it's working fine but for Android 10 OS it's not working. Below is my code. Tried using android:requestLecacyStorage=true but it's not helping.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                               getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf"));
                                /*Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
                                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile),"text/plain");
                                getContext().startActivity(i);*/
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                //toastMsg.showToast(TransInvoicePDFCreate.this, "No Application match to Open Print File");
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
```

Also tried using FileProvider

```
try {
                            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(InventoryPDFCreate.this,getPackageName(), pdfFile);
                            Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(InventoryPDFCreate.this)
                                    .setStream(uri) // uri from FileProvider
                                    .setType("text/html")
                                    .getIntent()
                                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) //Change if needed
                                    .setDataAndType(uri, "pdf/*")
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                    startActivity(intent);  // startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //toastMsg.showToast(TransInvoicePDFCreate.this, "No Application match to Open Print File");
                        }
```

Comment: Dont use Uri.fromFile(). Use FileProvider to serve your file. Needed since Android 7/N.

Comment: Google for a FileProvider example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078497/unable-to-send-pdf-file-via-intent-to-any-application-except-whatsapp

Comment: What is that link that you shared above?

Comment: That is to comfort you to not feel alone ;-)

Comment: `// uri from FileProvider` We can believe that. But you better show your code.

Comment: Have edited my question. Please see that

Comment: `pdfFile` ????? `"text/html"` ???? `.getIntent()` ????? `"pdf/*"` ?????

Comment: Need to print PDF file

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? FWIW, your MIME type in your second code snippet is wrong (twice), and it is unclear why you are using `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` (as you are replacing most of what it creates). [This sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) demonstrate viewing a PDF via `FileProvider`. In my case, the PDF is an asset that I copy to a local file before viewing.

Comment: @blackapps Done the job man. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, the MIME-type was the mistake. Changed it and it's working now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095409/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-view/68098285#68098285