# No Activity found to handle Intent (android.intent.action.VIEW)

Tags: android, exception

In my application am having a pdf which is to be printed by selecting the installed apps in the device. When I tried to open the application it throws "No Activity found to handle Intent". I have also added  in my manifest file but it's not helping. I have installed printshare in my emulator which used to print the pdf. Below is my code.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(InventoryPDFCreate.this,getPackageName(), pdfFile);
                                Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(InventoryPDFCreate.this)
                                        .setStream(uri) // uri from FileProvider
                                        .getIntent()
                                        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) //Change if needed
                                        .setDataAndType(uri, "pdf/*")
                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                        startActivity(intent); 

                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                toastMsg.showToast(InventoryPDFCreate.this, "No Application match to Open Print File"+e);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 100);
```

Manifest file

```
<queries>
        <!-- WebView -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>

        <!-- Camera -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>

        <!-- Gallery -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Am getting the below exception:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.mobilesalesperson.controller/external/Android/AMSP/PrintReport/msp.pdf typ=pdf/* flg=0x80001 (has extras) }
```

Comment: `setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")`?

Comment: Please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem was that the OP was using an incorrect mime-type as the parameter. Android does not support all types of mimes but this can be checked by using [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap).

> Return the MIME type for the given extension if supported, null otherwise.

```java
final String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
```